# Changing the line types with trellis doubleYScale plot

Tags: r

I did create a `doubleYScale` plot:

```
obj1 <- xyplot(Produktion ~ Year, datac1mw, type = "l",col="black")
obj2 <- xyplot(Summa.skulder ~ Year, datac1mw, type = "p",col="black")

hm=doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.ylab2 = TRUE,text = c("Produktion", "Summa.skulder"), 
             par.settings = simpleTheme(col = c('blue','black'), lty = 2:3))
```

The result I get is: 
[image]

What I really want is a plot where the `legend` shows not 2 lines (as now a blue and a red line) but that Produktion (left y-axis) is dotted and Summa.Skulder (right y-axis) is a line, in the legend.

Any suggestions?
Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
x <-1:10 # make data as I do not have yours
y <-1:10
z <-10:1

obj1 <- xyplot(y ~ x, type = "l",col="black")
obj2 <- xyplot(z ~ x, type = "p",col="black")

doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.ylab2 = TRUE)
update(doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, text = c("obj1", "obj2")),
par.settings = simpleTheme(col = c("black","black"), lty = 1:2))
```

[image]

This works for getting points and lines in the legend as your new comment says:

```
obj1 <- xyplot(y ~ x, type = "l",col="black",key = simpleKey(col=c('black'),
           text=c("Produktion"),points=FALSE, lines=TRUE))
obj2 <- xyplot(z ~ x, type = "p",col="black",key = simpleKey(col=c('black'),
           text=c("Summa.skulder"),lines=FALSE,points= TRUE))

doubleYScale(obj1, obj2, add.ylab2 = TRUE,par.settings = simpleTheme(col =   
              c("black","black")))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! But the problem is that I want the legend to show the type of the lines, not colors.. In example the legend would show a dotted black line and a black line. This picture will be included in an article and colors are not allowed, so the user would not be able to see which y-axis is what... Is it possible?

Comment: yes, but the `legend` still shows the solid line (obj1) and dots, but not small circles as in the picture for obj2. I would like to have small circles in the legend:) any idea?

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, but what if I want the legend to incorporate a solid line and a dashed line as I showed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856374/changing-legend-in-trellis-doubleyscale-plot ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Legend settings ares taken only from obj1. So it is better to set the *key* parmeter in the obj1.

You can set the panel settings in the obj2( I add an example as option)

```
foo <- list(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))
obj1 <- xyplot(y ~ x, foo,
               key = simpleKey(
                 text=c("Produktion", "Summa.skulder"),
                 col=c('blue','black'),points= FALSE,rectangles=TRUE,lines=TRUE))
obj2 <- xyplot(y^2 ~ x, foo
               , panel = function(...)panel.xyplot(type = "l",lty = 2,grid=TRUE,...))
## simple case: no axis for the overlaid plot
doubleYScale(obj1, obj2,add.ylab2 =TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! But the problem is that I want the `legend` to show the type of the lines, not colors.. In example the legend would show a dotted black line and a black line. This picture will be included in an article and colors are not allowed, so the user would not be able to see which y-axis is what... Is it possible?